# Find out whether all SVG images have loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a few image tags on a page to display SVG images as follows:

```
<image xlink:href="abc.."  />
<image xlink:href="xyz.."  />
```

Now I want to determine whether all images have loaded or not. I cannot use onload inside the image tag since I do not control the image tags. The tags are coming in the from of a string as  parameter. I simply change the inner html of a div to that string. Now is there any way to find out whether all images on the page have loaded or not?

Answer (score -1):

To check whether all images on the page have loaded or not?

let's say you have a bunch of images or SVG in this case in your HTML file
ex:

```
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-krysten-merriman-20787.jpg&fm=jpg"/>
```

To check wheter it loaded or not all you have to do is check image height.

here's an example

```
window.addEventListener("load", event => {
    var image = document.querySelector('img');
    var isLoaded = image.complete && image.naturalHeight !== 0;
    alert(isLoaded);
});
```

this function will run after the pages has been loaded it will select img tag and chekc complate state and check if image height not zero if  true it means the images have been loaded correctly if false then it did not.

Comment: Hello, actually complete attribute is not available for svg image. The document.querySelector('image') returns SVGImageElement instead of HTMLImageElement, and SVGImageElement does not seem to have an attribute named complete.

Comment: is the svg hosted by the same domain or are you referencing it because the restricted by the same-origin policy exits.

Comment: it comes from google cloud on the server.